# Dont understand this union of sets1

Tags: combinatorics

Find $|A \cap B|$ if $|A| = 7$, $|B| = 8$ and $|A\cup B| = 10$.

How is this possible?

Please help.

If |A| = 7, |B| = 8, then how is the cardinality of AUB less than 7 + 8.

If you have two sets, than how is the union of it less than the two sets?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: What if Alice, Bob and Charlie belong to a club $A$ and Bob, Charlie and David belong to club $B$. What members belong to either $A$ or $B$?

Comment: the union can be less than the sum of the two sets if some elements are in both A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left| A \cap B \right| = \left| A \right| + \left| B \right| - \left| A \cup B \right|$. Draw a [Venn diagramme](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/venn-diagrams.html), and you will see. The answer is $5$ ($= 7 + 8 - 10$).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.